# Springboot 2. hikaricp and Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: hikaricp

We have services written in Springboot 2 and we are using SQL Server as backend database and intermittently we are receiving below error

Hikaricp is 3.4.1 [compile]
Microsoft SQL Server 2014
Springboot 2.2.1

Failed to validate connection ConnectionID:XXXX(The connection is closed.). Possibly consider using a shorter maxLifetime value.

We have minimumIdle and Maximum pool size same as suggested by Hikari.

```
maximum-pool-size: 25
connection-timeout: 5000
idle-timeout: 0
max-lifetime: 300000
allow-pool-suspension: true
register-mbeans: true
leak-detection-threshold: 60000
```

Please suggest if we need to make MinimumIdle as 0 for Microsoft SQL Server ?
Will it cause any performance impacts ?